# What's wrong if I replace a signal light bulb, but it still acts as if it's burnt out?

Tags: electrical, turn-signal, towing

I hit the ditch the other day and got towed out.  There was no physical damage as far as I can tell, but whenever I indicated right, it would blink fast as if a bulb was burned out.

I replaced the front bulb, because it appeared to be burned out.  But the new bulb didn't work either.  Upon closer inspection, the old bulb's elements appeared to be undamaged, and the new bulb actually did still blink, but extremely dimly (and still fast).

Did the tow rope accidentally pinch (but not break) a wire while getting towed?  Is it just a fluke with the new bulb and I should try another?  Fuse?  Any other ideas?

2005 Dodge Grand Caravan

Comment: This definitely sounds like a wiring issue. Was there any damage caused when hitting the ditch? Where was the tow rope placed? If there is any current getting through, the fuse is fine. The dim blink suggests a poor connection somewhere in the chain. Look for damage in the connectors and wires.

Comment: You're right.  There was a short in the wiring.  If you would have actually answered instead of commented, I could have marked your answer correct.  But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a short in the wiring.

Answer (score 1):

Double check side marker/turn indicator bulbs. Many times a side bulb will stop working (check the good side to ensure you know where to look on the bad side) causing the same fast blinking which you see when a front or tail light has gone dark.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have a side light, just a front and back.

Comment: All cars have some way to display a turn on the side. This is so people located at the side of your vehicle know your intentions. It's required on cars in the US and Europe. There may be a small bulb or a something you've overlooked.